# Tree List Ex Editor - change adding of selected item to the top of the list instead of bottom

Tags: editor, sitecore, treelist

One of our clients has a website that uses a lot of TreeListEx type field. By default, when an item is selected and moved over to the right side in the TreeListEx editor, the selected element is added to the bottom of the list on the right. The editors for this client would like to have this changed so that the element is added to the top of the list on the right.

For this I tried to look in the Shell folder at Treeview.js and Treelistexeditor.js. But I could not figure where to make the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `TreeListExEditor.js` file, look at the `scSetMastersType.prototype.moveRight()` function. In a loop it calls `selected.appendChild(opt)` which you may want to change to prepend the option. This would require a bit of JavaScript hackery on your part.

Perhaps start with a `typeof(selected)` to see what it is. I assume an array. If so, maybe do this:

1. Reverse the original array
2. Append your new item at the end of the revered data
3. Reverse it again to back to normal. Now your new option is at the beginning

Again, because this is JavaScript, there are plenty approaches you can take.